# Disable automatic permission request

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to check if the Motion permission is enabled or not, but the only way I have found is this (support pre iOS 11 also):

```
CMMotionActivityManager * activityManager =  [[CMMotionActivityManager alloc]init];
NSDate* today = [NSDate date];

[activityManager queryActivityStartingFromDate:today toDate:today toQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(NSArray<CMMotionActivity *> * _Nullable activities, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    NSLog(@"result is %d",error && error.code != CMErrorMotionActivityNotAvailable);
    }];
}
```

But I don't want to ask automatically for the permission, only check its status.
Is it possible?

Comment: Ah, permission checking for the Activity Manager doesn’t seem to have been available before iOS 11. The automatic request was created to ensure permission was asked before use, and I’m not aware of any way to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use authorizationStatus class property.

```
 if (CMMotionActivityManager.authorizationStatus == CMErrorMotionActivityNotAvailable)
```

This should not fire permission request.

Comment: Yes, but this for iOS 11+, what about pre?

Comment: @ZachBublil I'd suggest that you go with: `if @available(iOS 11, *) {...` and use the `authorizationStatus`; for pre-iOS 11 you probably have to live with the automatic permission request. But at least its only for a small fration of users who still use pre-11

Answer (score 0):

To check status only, use the class function `authorizationStatus`.

`CMMotionActivityAuthorizationStatus status = [CMMotionActivityManager authorizationStatus]`

This returns a value from the `CMAuthorizationStatus` enum:

- notDetermined
- restricted
- denied
- authorized

`notDetermined` means your app hasn’t asked for permission yet.

Use the function `isActivityAvailable` to determine “[whether motion data is available on the device](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionactivitymanager)“

Comment: This is for iOS 11 +

Comment: You right but once you initialize an instance of it you will be prompted to grant permission,So not helping.